# How to request permission using ViewModel

Tags: android, viewmodel, android-permissions, zxing

I need to implement a QR scanner using **Zxing** and **Zxing Android Embedded** as an Activity and I'd like to use ViewModel for it, but I don't know the way to request or check if the permission are given or not. When I did it using MVP the flow as :

Activity > `presenter.onViewReady(this)` > `view.requestPremission()` > onActivityResult was checking the permission if it was ok then > `presenter.doStuff()`

But how's the way to do it with ViewModel?

Comment: view model should not be concerned about UI stuff and asking for permission is UI related so really there should be no difference. Once you requested permission (or checked permission is granted) in your activity then call the view model

Comment: So, that's why the MVP and MVVM are different in terms of View - Presenter and View - ViewModel, right? So then I have to request permissions from Activity, and once they accepted it, I have to call viewModel then?

Comment: Yes that is how it should work

Answer (score 0):

So far in Android you can receive permission only from an `Activity`. In order to check and request permissions directly from the `ViewModel` I would suggest to introduce the following two entities:

- `PermissionManager` -- is a high-level interface for managing permissions. You are suggested to use the implementation of this interface at `ViewModel` level.

  ```
  interface PermissionManager {
      boolean checkPermissionGranted(String permission);

       // Returns false if user have previously checked "Don't ask again"
       // option for your permission
      boolean requestPermission(String permission);
  }
  ```
- `PermissionProvider` -- is who actually allows `PermissionManager` to ask the system for a particular permission.

  ```
  interface PermissionProvider {
       interface Callback{
          void onPermissionGranted(String permission);
       }
       boolean requestPermission(String permission);
  }
  ```

  As I have mentioned, you can request permissions only from an `Activity`, so your `Activity` provides permission for your app and should:

  1. implement `PermissionProvider` interface and the logic that you already have in  `view.requestPremission()` from your question;
  2. attach itself (`PermissionProvider`) to `PermissionManager` in `onStart()` and detach itself in `onStop()`.

Benefits of such approach is that you can check and ask permissions when you realy need it. You might also implement various `PermissionProvider`s if `Android SDK` will make is possible to ask for permissions not only from an `Activity`.

Comment: Ok, I'll try thanks, could yo put a simple example with the viewmodel?